# What does "grabbing a stick on the beach" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does "grabbing a stick on the beach" mean?

> After a long day of sunbathing and cooling off in the ocean, George Smith took a lone walk along what appeared to be a deserted beach.   Finally, George came upon a “another shorter, square-cut man,” who thought he too was alone and *grabbed a stick on the beach* and began drawing in the sand. George was awestruck, as he had surely encountered his idol, Picasso.

Comment: I can't see it meaning anything other than the individual words themselves.

Answer (score 3):

It is just a literal statement.  He was drawing in the sand with a stick, and apparently was doing so very well.

Answer (score 1):

A stick -- usually a small branch or a large twig.

... grabbed {a stick **on** the beach }  ...

The stick was lying on the sand.  The prepositional phrase is not adverbial but attaches to the noun.

To grab -- to take hold of something roughly or with a quick motion,  casually or spontaneously, not slowly and deliberately and without any delicacy or precision or careful choosing.

> He grabbed **the book on the table** and began to read from it.